# Enable bluetooth with Android Management API

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-management-api

I have noticed that some devices have bluetooth enabled by default (after a factory reset) and some others don't.

In my [Android Management API policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy) I would like to specify that bluetooth should be enabled.

I've tried setting [bluetoothDisabled](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#Policy.FIELDS.bluetooth_disabled) to `false` but it doesn't have any effect: after provisioning the device bluetooth's status is the default one.

How can I force bluetooth to be enabled with [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management) ?

Comment: Hello, I found you with many questions with Android Enterprise. I have some basic questions. I searched a lot but didn't found proper solutions.

I am developing a parental control app like Google Family Link for the child. Is it possible to develop an app like that using Android Enterprise? Can we disable/enable the app, lock/unlock devices using AE? Also, Can I track location, block/unblock all app installation and uninstallation? I found that we can manage only fully device or work profile only. So is it possible to develop this kind of app using Android Enterprise?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I am also interested in this question. Have you found the answer?

Comment: @ВладиславСтариков See Fred's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Management API doesn't offer to enable/disable Bluetooth directly at the moment.

However you can implement a companion app that controls the Bluetooth state through [`BluetoothAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) `enable()` and `disable()` methods. To do so:

1. Create an Android app (the "companion" app) and upload it to Play (possibly as a [private app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139))
2. Set a policy to force install this app, grant it all permissions (so it gets the permission `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`) and [launch it during setup](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#launch_an_app_during_setup):

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.example.companion",
      "installType": "REQUIRE_FOR_SETUP",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
  ],
  "setupActions":[
      {
         "launchApp":{
            "packageName":"com.example.companion"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

3. When the companion app launches call [`BluetoothAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) `enable()` or `disable()` as needed
4. (Optional) Implement [managed configurations](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) in the companion app to be able to configure it from the Android Management API via [`ApplicationPolicy.managedConfiguration`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy).

You can also use the companion app for additional purposes if needed. Common use cases include: status page for your service, debug interface for admins, etc.